# Dynamic jquery changes springboot and thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, if-statement, thymeleaf

want to know how i can solve this. i have an ajax that return a list of bool, and depending if its true or false, want to return one or other style. The problems is that the DOM element that i want to change it is created dynamically.

here is the thymeleaf:

```
<form name="votesys" class="mr-auto" th:action="@{/votecreate}" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:object="${vote}" method="post">
                                        <input name="tapa" type="hidden" th:object="${tapa}" th:value="${tapa.id}" />
                                        <!-- //una instancia de user por una instancia de voto, un voto muchas tapas, eso creo-->
                                        <input name="user" type="hidden" th:value="${usuario}" />
                                        <input class="votolove" name="voto" type="submit" value="&#xf004;">
                                    </form>
                                    <a th:text="'Quitar voto'" th:href="@{/votedelete/} + ${tapa.id}" style="float:right;"></a>
```

the AJAX get request :

```
const full = $('input[class="votolove"]');
    //full.attr("value", "\uf004").css({"font-family": "'Font Awesome 5 Free'"});
    //full.css({"font-weight": "900"});
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/isvoted",
        success: function(result) {       

            if (result === undefined || result.length == 0 || typeof(result) === "string"){
                console.log("no hay votos");
            }else{
                for (var voto of result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if(voto === true){
                        full.prop('disabled', true);
                        console.log(voto);
                    }else{
                        full.prop('disabled', false);
                        console.log(voto);
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

Aclarations: The result return a object of booleans, and the vote return true or false.
             I tried to use the input gettin his name, the class but doesnt work, when i tried the id it says that the DOM page should dont have the same id for the elements of the DOM

i was trying to able and disabled the button but it doesn't work, it seems it get the last value of the condition and apply this to all elements.
Thanks for the support, this its getting me mad

Comment: how does your ajax get called? onclick of `voto` button ?  Also , i didn't understood your question `input gettin his name, the class but doesnt work..` ?  what do you mean by this can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Swati , my ajax its called when jQuery(document).ready() . That i tried to get the refer the input with the input name, the input class and doesnt work, and when i tried to refer the input with the id, the console says me that there are elements in the dom with the same id

Comment: sorry my english :S

Comment: did you tried like this -> `const full = $(".votolove");` ? check and see if that works .

Comment: it doesnt work, but thanks. it seems the input only attend to the last value of the condition of the for each, and set this last value to all input element that are genereted (i don have sayed yet but the the content is generated dinamically).

Comment: @Swati u kwno what occured here?

Comment: You are applying same effect to all button with `full` ? what does `result` has in it ? does it showing correct value ? because you said `input only attend to the last value of the condition ..` maybe you are not getting right values .check and see that .

Comment: thats it, there is setting the effect to all the buttons full. The result return a list of bool. I have tried with an html button instead of input, but still not working, i dont kwnow why it get the last value of the condition and set to all the input elements. Really thanks for helping me. @Swati